# Jupyter's tab auto-complete is not working for several libraries like- sklearn, numpy, seaborn, pandas and matplotlib etc

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Whenever I am using jupyter in the default directory (used by jupyter after installing anaconda) tab auto complete works fine. After entering a dot if I press the tab the list of methods and attributes appears.

Now, if I launch Jupyter notebook from a different location (say D drive) using `anaconda prompt (command line)`, jupyter notebook appears, but for several libraries like `sklearn, numpy, seaborn, pandas and matplotlib` tab auto-complete after a dot is **not working**. However, when I write:

`from sklearn.`

and then press tab then I can see the options, similarly for other libraries too (below is one such screenshot).

[image]

Surprisingly the same **never** happens when I write:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import seaborn as sb

np.                   # nothing appears upon pressing Tab after a dot
sb.                   # nothing appears upon pressing Tab after a dot
sklearn.              # nothing appears upon pressing Tab after a dot
```

I have read some solutions on the internet where they mention about some plugin/extensions to use, but I don't want them to be used, I kind of prefer what jupyter already offers.

Could someone please help me with this issue...?

P.s.: I'm not still sure with what all other libraries the issue still persists, I happen to frequently use these so far....

Comment: I have the exact same problem. No solution found yet.